# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate

Tags: java, maven

I using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=$archetype_groupId -DarchetypeArtifactId=$archetype_artifactId -DarchetypeVersion=$archetype_version -Dpackage=$package -DgroupId=$groupId -DartifactId=$artifactId -Dversion=$version  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: java.io.IOException: 没有那个文件或目录 -> [Help 1]

[DEBUG]   - found resource (archetype-resources/)service/src/test/resources/scf_local.config
[DEBUG]   - ignored resource META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Processing complete archetype zzdealdemo
[DEBUG] Processing module hook
[DEBUG] Processing module rootArtifactId hook
[DEBUG] Processing module pom /etc/hook/pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing module moduleOffset
[DEBUG] Processing module outputDirectoryFile /etc/hook
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project moduleId hook
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project pom /etc/hook/pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project moduleOffset
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project outputDirectoryFile /etc/hook
[DEBUG] Processing fileset project basedirPom /etc/pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing pom /etc/hook/pom.xml
[DEBUG] Processing template archetype-resources/pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.950s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 16 11:25:56 CST 2019
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: java.io.IOException: 没有那个文件或目录 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: java.io.IOException: 没有那个文件或目录
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: java.io.IOException: 没有那个文件或目录
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I use java Runtime class execute the shell script.There is no problem executing the script directly,The Runtime class using Java executes the error shown above

Answer (score 0):

Try this below command to create maven project through CMD mode and let me know if any issue is there...

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=TestCases -DartifactId=FrameworkProject -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeVersion=1.1
```